# How to customize a JSP that include another one

Tags: forms, jsp, include

I'm using an include directive in 3 jsps in order to have the common part in one jsp, and then add the specific part to each single jsp.
Now in the common jsp I have a form with some input tags.

My question is, how can I add new input tag within the same form declared in the common jsp?

Beyond this, I was also wandering if the include method is actually the best solution.

Thanks in advance,
Ettore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any element in the form using javascript as shown below.

```
function add(type) {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.setAttribute("type", type);
    element.setAttribute("value", type);
    element.setAttribute("name", type);
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
    foo.appendChild(element);
}
```

However, adding fields like this is not a good idea. The common jsp should only include the component which are constants. If you want to add in the form then, you need to declare the form in the enclosing jsp.